# writing an API class for RestKit framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, restkit, afnetworking

I switched from AFnetworking to RestKit. In AFnetworking had an API class. The API.h class contained the following.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
typedef void (^JSONResponseBlock)(NSDictionary* json);
@interface API : NSObject
//the authorized user
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary* user;

+(API*)sharedInstance;
//check whether there's an authorized user

//send an API command to the server
-(void)loginCommand:(NSMutableDictionary*)params onCompletion:(JSONResponseBlock)completionBlock;
```

And my API.m class looks like this.

```
+(API *)sharedInstance
{
    static API *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^ {
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAPIHost]];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

#pragma mark - init
//intialize the API class with the destination host name

-(API *)init
{
    //call super init
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil){
        //initialize the object
        user = nil;

        [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

        // Accept HTTP Header; see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)loginCommand:(NSMutableDictionary *)params onCompletion:(JSONResponseBlock)completionBlock{
    NSLog(@"%@%@",kAPIHost,kAPILogin);
    NSMutableURLRequest *apiRequest = [self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:kAPILogin parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData){
        //TODO: attach file if needed

    }];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:apiRequest];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
        //success!
        NSLog(@"SUCCESSSS!");
        completionBlock(responseObject);
    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
        //Failure
        NSLog(@"FAILUREE!");
        completionBlock([NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[error localizedDescription] forKey:@"error"]);
    }];
    [operation start];

}
```

Like you can see I only instantiate it once and put all my methods in over here. In my view controller I only need to call this method with a parameter-dictionary. Then I could read the whole JSON file.

Now with restKit I do this all on viewController level. I want to split it up like I did by AFNetworking. This is what I do in RestKit, At the moment is this all on viewController level.

```
   //let AFNetworking manage the activity indicator
[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;

// Initialize HTTPClient
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://virtuele-receptie.preview.sanmax.be"];
AFHTTPClient* client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
//we want to work with JSON-Data
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:RKMIMETypeJSON];

// Initialize RestKit
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];


//Do mapping

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:dataMapping
                                                                                   pathPattern:nil
                                                                                       keyPath:@"data"
                                                                                   statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:_txtLogin.text,@"email",_txtPass.text,@"pwd", nil];

[objectManager getObject:nil path:@"/nl/webservice/company-user/login/apikey/key12345678" parameters:dict
                 success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                   //Success  
                 }
                 failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                     //Failure
                 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

So far with RestKit I haven't seen a huge need for an API class like you might create with other HTTP frameworks. RestKit has its own HTTP client (actually, just AFNetworking's client), so there's no need to have a class for your HTTP client, and I've found that each time I use the RKObjectManager I generally want access to the method parameters and block callbacks within each view controller. In other words, I don't want to run RestKit networking code in an API class, because I would essentially have to wrap the entire call in a method that can be accessed in the view controller (success block, failure block, etc).

In essence, RestKit's design lightens the networking code so much that in my experience with it - 3 or 4 apps now - I've yet to see enough reason write an API class like you describe.